# Check Google Sheet for emails, verify delivery by api and Subscribe via api Benchmark

Tags: python, api, google-sheets

The main objective of this bot to make fast and reliable automatic subscriptions to email newsletter for people, who filled the website form(submissions go to google sheet)

I had too many requests to google docs.(rate limit error) -> so i added sleep 5 after every subscription. Also added break into email-check loop.(to avoid subscribing too many in 1 loop)

```
# pylint: disable=missing-module-docstring
import quickemailverification
import json
import sentry_sdk
import re
import requests
import traceback
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mod import *
import gspread
import urllib3
from os import system
import time
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

client = quickemailverification.Client(
    'eed14e5a')  # key blurred


sentry_sdk.init("https://322.ingest.sentry.io/334",  # key blurred
                traces_sample_rate=1.0)


def regex(regex, text):
    '''If find this text-return True'''
    return bool(re.search(regex, text))


def checkemail(email):
    '''Api for email deliverability True-means many metrics are fine'''
    quickemailverification = client.quickemailverification()
    response = quickemailverification.verify(email)
    if response.body["safe_to_send"] == "true":
        return True
    else:
        return False


# pylint: disable=missing-module-docstring
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

# For clarity in opened windows cmd(i just run .py file and they all ahve same title)
system("Ben EMail")

r = requests


def subscribe(email, name="", proxy="", debug=False):
    if debug:
        proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"

    proxies = {
        "https": proxy
    }

    burp0_url = "https://api.benchmarkemail.com"
    burp0_cookies = {
        "Key": "M1oqxE5kauGh55V12W2J"  # key blurred
    }
    burp0_headers = {}
    burp0_data = {
        "doubleoptin": "1",
        "fldEmail": email,
        "fldfirstname": name,
        "fldlastname": ''
    }
    r = requests.post(burp0_url,
                      headers=burp0_headers,
                      cookies=burp0_cookies,
                      data=burp0_data,
                      verify=False,
                      proxies=proxies,
                      timeout=10)

    if regex("Check your inbox", r.text):
        # check response html text
        print("Subscribed", name, email, r.status_code)
        success = True
    else:
        print("Error", name, email, "status code", r.status_code)
        success = False
    return success, r.text


credentials = {
    "type": "service_account",
    # key blurred
}
gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(credentials)
sh = gc.open("email_form")
ws = sh.get_worksheet(0)


def parse_bmresponse(response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    result = soup.find("div", {"class": "content-section"})
    # apart from parsing response for "success phrase" i save api responses for further investigations
    return result.get_text()


def dotable():  # go through the whole table and find who is not subscribed yet
    all_values = ws.get_all_values()
    rownum = 1
    for row in all_values[1:]:
        rownum += 1
        if row[2] == "subscribed" or row[2] == "error":
            pass
        elif row[2] == "":
            name = row[0]
            email = row[1]
            print(fr"Empty status {name},{email} on {rownum} ")
            success, response = subscribe(email, name)
            if success:
                # Change status if subbed
                ws.update("C" + str(rownum), 'moded_ok')
                # response from email delivery api
                check_result = "Can send "+str(checkemail(email))
                # raw result from subsription func
                ws.update("F" + str(rownum), check_result)
                # response from email delivery api
                ws.update("G" + str(rownum), parse_bmresponse(response))
                break
            else:
                ws.update("C" + str(rownum), 'moded_noluck')
                ws.update("F" + str(rownum), check_result)
                ws.update("G" + str(rownum), parse_bmresponse(response))
                break
        else:
            pass


while 1 > 0:
    try:
        dotable()
        time.sleep(5)

    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        print("Timeout server, i sleep 15")
        time.sleep(15)

    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        sentry_sdk.capture_exception()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Exceptions

Using `except Exception` to ignore exceptions without knowing the exact causes is often not a great idea. It makes it hard for someone unfamiliar with the code to tell what kinds of exceptions are expected, and also means that when things go wrong in unexpected ways the program doesn't stop doing things but instead *keeps doing the wrong thing*, which is *often* harmless, but can get pretty nasty at times

It also ends up capturing `KeyboardInterrupt`, which is probably not very important, but still a bit annoying

Credit for using an exception handling framework and taking care to log errors, though

### Imports

The `import json` and `from mod import *` lines don't seem necessary - as far as I can tell those never get used

### Globals

Global variables tend to make program state a bit harder to reason about, and make the functions that use them a bit less flexible. Consider passing values like `ws` and `client` as parameters to the functions that use them instead

### `regex`

Helper functions are nice, but this one in particular seems redundant. It's only used in one place, and `if re.search("Check your inbox", r.text)` should work fine there. Actually, since that's just a plain string and not a regex at all, `if "Check your inbox" in r.text` should work just as well and probably perform slightly better

### Naming

Conventionally, words are split using underscores `like_so`. Names like `checkemail`, `parse_bmresponse` and `dotable` would usually be written like `check_email`, `parse_bm_response` and `do_table`

That said, those names aren't as descriptive as I think they could be, though:

- Checking an email does describe what `check_email` does - but it might be clearer to say *what* it checks. A name like `can_send_to`, or `is_reachable_email` seems like a good fit
- "Do something to a table" feels like a less clear summary of what that function does than "update the subscriptions", so a name like `add_subscriptions` might seem a bit more appropriate. It might not be the *best* name, sure, but I do prefer it over `do_table`
- The name `parse_bmresponse` could be clearer if it stated *how* it parsed it and what data it extracts. Something like `get_response_text` or `get_text_content` seems like a good summary to me

And speaking of clarity, I appreciate the docstrings that are present, but it'd be nice if the rest of the functions also had some

### `checkemail`

I did mention passing `client` as a parameter, but do we need to create a new `Quickemailverification` each time, or might it make more sense to pass *that* as a parameter instead? I haven't used the `quickemailverification` library before, and their docs website seems to be down right now, so I can't check

Also, when there's an `if` that only serves to determine whether to `return True` or `return False`, you usually don't need the `if` - the `if`/`return`s can be simplified to `return response.body["safe_to_send"] == "true"`, since that expression is already a `bool`

All in all, you might be able to get something close to:

```py
def can_send_to(email, verifier):
    '''Api for email deliverability True-means many metrics are fine'''
    response = verifier.verify(email)
    return response.body["safe_to_send"] == "true"
```

### `dotable`

One issue here is that each call to `Workspace.update` sends a separate request. We can avoid that by using `Workspace.batch_update` instead

We might want to consider limiting ourselves to only fetching part of the worksheet by passing a range (like `"A1:G"`, or even a limited number of rows like `"A1:G500"`) to `Workspace.get_values`

When iterating over a list, if you find yourself wanting both the content and the position, the right tool for the job is the builtin `enumerate`, as in `for index, row in enumerate(rows):`. There is no need to keep track of an index manually

Why does the program check separately for the statuses `subscribed` and `error`? It doesn't do anything special in those cases
On a related note, `else: pass` is never necessary. That `if`/`elif`/`else` branch can be trimmed down to only an `if row[2] == "":` block

Where would the values `subscribed` or `error` come from, anyway? This program uses the values `moded_ok` and `moded_noluck` for that column, doesn't it? Are there *multiple* programs adding subscriptions?

If subscribing fails, we try to update column F with the value of the variable `check_result` - which hasn't been defined at that point, causing the entire function to fail with a `NameError`. That's not ideal

Since we `break` after attempting to subscribe once, we only ever handle one subscription each time we fetch the sheet. This feels inefficient - is there a reason not to do several at once? That could let us fetch the spreadsheet less often, and would reduce the risk of falling behind if there's a lot of new subscribers, right?

All in all, I might've done something closer to:

```py
def add_subscriptions(worksheet, email_verifier):
    """
    Attempt to add subscriptions for the people in the worksheet that haven't previously been handled
    """
    sheet_range = "A1:G"
    values = worksheet.get_values(sheet_range)

    for index, row in enumerate(values):
        if row[2] == "":
            name = row[0]
            email = row[1]
            print(fr"Empty status {name},{email} on {index + 1} ")
            success, response = subscribe(email, name)
            if success:
                row[2] = 'moded_ok'
                row[5] = "Can send " + str(can_send_to(email, email_verifier))
            else:
                row[2] = 'moded_noluck'
                row[5] = "Subscription failed"
            
            row[6] = get_response_text(response)
    
    worksheet.batch_update([{
        "range": sheet_range,
        "values": values
    }])
```

Alternatively, I might try to use the `Cell` class with `Workspace.range` and `Workspace.update_cells`, which might look more like this:

```py
def add_subscriptions(worksheet, email_verifier):
    """
    Attempt to add subscriptions for the people in the worksheet that haven't previously been handled
    """
    row_count = worksheet.row_count
    
    all_cells = worksheet.range(f"A1:G{row_count}")

    rows = (tuple(v) for _, v in itertools.groupby(all_cells, Cell.row.fget))

    updated_cells = []

    for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
        if row[2].value == "":
            name = row[0].value
            email = row[1].value
            print(fr"Empty status {name},{email} on {row_number} ")
            success, response = subscribe(email, name)
            if success:
                row[2].value = 'moded_ok'
                row[5].value = "Can send " + str(can_send_to(email, email_verifier))
            else:
                row[2].value = 'moded_noluck'
                row[5].value = "Subscription failed"
            
            row[6].value = get_response_text(response)
            
            updated_cells += (row[2], row[5], row[6])
    
    if updated_cells:
        worksheet.update_cells(updated_cells)
```

### Top-level code

To allow a module to be `import`ed, it's usually a good idea to put top-level code in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. It's not always important, but it's a good habit to get into, and it also means the code is bundled into a single block instead of possibly being scattered all throughout the file

On a related note, `InsecureRequestWarning`s get disabled in two different places. Once should be enough, since they don't get re-enabled inbetween
Side note, those warnings are there for a reason - verifying certificates is usually a good idea. Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

I don't think `system("Ben EMail")` will set the window title - is it meant to be `system("title Ben EMail")`?

The `r = requests` line doesn't seem necessary - that value never ends up used since you spell out `requests` when actually using it, and the name `r` does get used for other variables in other places, so this just winds up confusing

`while 1 > 0` works, but is a bit unusual. `while True` is the usual way to write an infinite loop

All in all, I'd suggest gathering the rest of the non-function non-import code into something a bit like:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

    client = quickemailverification.Client(
        'eed14e5a')  # key blurred

    qev = client.quickemailverification()

    #pylint: disable=E0110
    sentry_sdk.init("https://322.ingest.sentry.io/334",  # key blurred
                    traces_sample_rate=1.0)

    # Set console window title
    system("title Ben EMail")

    credentials = {
        "type": "service_account",
        # key blurred
    }
    gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(credentials)
    sh = gc.open("email_form")
    ws = sh.get_worksheet(0)

    while True:
        try:
            add_subscriptions(ws, qev)
            time.sleep(5)

        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            print("Timeout server, i sleep 15")
            time.sleep(15)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            sentry_sdk.capture_exception()
            raise
```

Comment: Firstly Sara, thank you so much for taking time and writing such a detailed reply for me! I really appreciate that and hope to be good enough one day to help people as much as you helped me to understand ways to improve.


Question. 
1) Could you please explain why you do (i mean is there a more intuitive way?)
     row = all_values[row_number - 1]

It took me a while to understand the basic conflict, that google doc starts with 1, and not with 0 row. For me the easiest version turned out to me my own row counter. 
I get puzzled every time when different providers start with 0 or 1).

Comment: 2) The reason for break after every successful subscription is to avoid rate limiting by google sheets (which i encountered several times). I couldn't thing of any other way to get around it, because every update in a table is done per-request basis. (i don't know a way to dl local copy of gspreadsheet, update it, and without errors replace a cloud copy of it)

3)InsecureRequestWarnings was disabled for successfull debugging with local proxy)

Once again. Amazing response and ton to learn!

Comment: @BogdanMind That makes sense, I was only thinking about the reading, not the writing. And, yes, in hindsight I picked a weird way to deal with the row counter. I'll try to update the review with those things in mind